# Android why is RecyclerView Adapter crashing?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` list that chooses between two layouts, a default layout and a `CardView` layout with the Adapter.  The default UI layout is shown first when the user has not yet created any `CardView`'s.  The layout switches to the `CardView` layout after the user creates and saves a `CardView`.  The layouts switch using "viewType", switching between 0 and 1.

The switching between the layouts was working fine when I used these two methods:

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size()>0 ? contactList.size():1;
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return contactList.size() == 0 ? 0:1;
}
```

Then I added the below method for another use and the app is crashing:

```
public Contact getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.jdw.v52/com.wimso.v052.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size
>   is 0
>                                                                            at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>                                                                            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>                                                                            at
>   com.wimso.v052.adapter.ContactListAdapter.getItem(ContactListAdapter.java:95)
>                                                                            at
>   com.wimso.v052.adapter.ContactListAdapter.clear(ContactListAdapter.java:72)
>                                                                            at com.wimso.v052.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.java:171)
>                                                                            at com.wimso.v052.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:126)

```
Adapter.java
...
public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
} 

public void add(Contact item) {
    if (contactList.size()==0) {
        // if list is empty 
        // remove empty cards first
        contactList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    contactList.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(contactList.size() -1);
}

public void clear() {
    while (getItemCount() > 0) {
        remove(getItem(0));
    }
}

// Remove an item from the RecyclerView/
public void remove(Contact item) {
    if (contactList.size()==0) {
        // if no more contacts in list,
        // we rebuild from scratch
        contactList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    int position = contactList.indexOf(item);
    if (position > -1) {
        contactList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, contactList.size());  // I added this.
    }
}

// Get the Item's position.
public Contact getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

// Update the existing List of RecyclerView items.
public void addAll(List<Contact> contactList) {
    for (Contact contact : contactList) {
        add(contact);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size()>0 ? contactList.size():1;
}

// if there are zero CardViews, use viewType 0 to get default_layout,
// otherwise provide a viewType of 1 to for each CardView in order to
// show the singlecard_layout.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return contactList.size() == 0 ? 0:1;
}

// Get the Item's Id.
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position).getId();
}

private static class DefaultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    DefaultViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

private class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CountDownTimer timer;
    ...
    private ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    ...
    @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == 0) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.defaultcard_layout, parent, false);
        return new DefaultViewHolder(itemView);
    } else {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent, false);
...
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (type == 1) {
        Contact contact = contactList.get(position);
        final ContactViewHolder holder = (ContactViewHolder) viewHolder;
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
public int getItemCount() {
   return contactList.size()>0 ? contactList.size():1;
}
```

When the `contactList` is 0 in size, you are still returning the RecyclerView to have at least 1 view. That one view tries to access your `contactList` which is already 0 and thus this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

You can do this:

```
public int getItemCount() {
      return contactList.size() != null ? contactList.size() : 0;
}
```

in case you get a null contactList.

or

```
public int getItemCount() {
   return contactList.size();
}
```

if you never input a null `contactList` to the adapter, simply returning the list size will do.

Comment: Ok, but if I just use "return contactList.size();" then the layouts don't switch properly when the size goes from 0 (should show default layout) to 1 or more (show the CardView layout)...any thoughts?

Comment: You should not use getItemType for such purpose. This is used for creating multiple views types inside a single recyclerView. Use a different approach.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to better switch between the two CardView layouts?

Comment: Change your layout manager and call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter if you have a different layout altogether.

Comment: Or simply change the view type and call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example of changing the view type?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your adapter's `getItem()` and `getItemId()` do not properly check that the contact list is empty. Since your adapter reports a size of 1 even if that list is empty, those methods will be called because the RecyclerView expects to have an item to show.

You seem to be trying to show a different view when the adapter has no items. While it is possible to do this in the adapter alone, I think it would be simpler and cleaner to have a separate `View` in your layout and simply change the visibility accordingly whenever you load the list of contacts. This way your adapter doesn't need to be nearly as complicated.

```
adapter.setItems(list); // or add, whatever
if (list.size() > 0) {
    recyclerView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
} else {
    emptyView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar crash that is due to the theme of the hosting activity.

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`

My activity was transparent with a fragment which has a recyclerview inside. Everything would load but upon rotation I get the same error. Nothing is wrong with my fragment or recyclerview implementation it was the style on the activity. Removing fixes the issue.